# jsp page loading very slowly

Tags: java, jsp

I have created a jsp page with database connectivity. This page has both html content and java programming.My database consists of a list of ip addresses.

My java code fetches each ip address and checks whether it is currently alive on the network or not. So my jsp page loads only after this java code has performed checks on all ip addresses.This is why my page loads very late.

Is there any remedy to this so that my page loads quicker??

Comment: You should separate java code from jsp pages

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues:

1. binding your JSP directly into your actual functionality. It would be preferable to implement [some MVC structuring](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm), and to allow the JSP to issue commands, and display whether those commands are being executed, if results are available etc. e.g. a command from the JSP to your servlet would initiate the processing (in a separate thread), and set state such that the JSP can report that 'processing' is in progress.
2. Your core functionality is to interrogate different IP addresses. That could easily be parallelised, such that you issue each IP query on a separate thread (naive solution, admittedly). Check out the [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) frameworks for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all ip addresses from db into an ArrayList and also load all ips which are alive into another ArrayList and compare these two arrays. This should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Separating JSP from Java code is one best practice, but the idea I'll describe here is more generally about separating the retrieval and updating of data from the rendering of the data, which is a common problem to solve.

What you need to do is separate the java code making all the network calls from the JSP which is being rendered. You can have the network calls all being run in one thread, checking each address once per minute or every few minutes, and updating each address' database record with a status. Then when the JSP is called, the JSP just grabs the latest data from the database and displays it (which is how JSP's should be used).

Now, there are numerous ways to accomplish this. If I were doing it myself, I would use Spring Framework and put the network-calling code in a method annotated with @Scheduled, and the network calls and database update could be done from that method. Details on how to use Spring are outside the scope of this answer, but hopefully this gives you an idea of the overall approach, and one technology you could start investigating.

Comment: I think there's a degree of scope creep here. The OP doesn't necessarily want to continually ping across his network. If the network check is more than a ping (e.g. an HTTP HEAD on a loaded server) then this could be quite intensive. If you did want to schedule this, I'd perhaps recommend the Timer() class as an initial pass solution that doesn't require adopting Spring

Comment: The original functionality provides real-time network status, and this answer provides near real-time status. In terms of features, I would argue that this is not scope creep at all. And if there were 1000 users accessing the page at once, this approach in fact drastically reduces the network activity. I did presume that the OP is using a ping, maybe that was a poor assumption. If the network activity is too much, the data refresh rate can be tweaked to balance the requirement for fresh data against the requirement for network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

-You should load JSP page only with IP list and after it's loaded, you can fetch IP adress statuses with AJAX requests.
 
-Earlier mentioned idea of caching statuses is a great. 
-Also you can improve interface (paging, lazy loading lists, etc) to reduce count of IP addresses for checking.